# GEt only filename instead of whole path

Tags: c#

I am making project on getting all text files from a selected drive. The thing is I am getting names of all text files along with path but all I need is name. I don't want to even get the extension, all I want is name of that text file. I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find the right answer. I am storing all those names in a listbox. here is my code:

```
String[] dir1 = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\");
for (int i = 0; i < dir1.Length; i++)
{
    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(dir1[i]);

    if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != fileAttributes.Hidden)
    {
        string folder = @""+ dir1[i];
        txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(txtfiles);
    }
}
```

How can I get only names, instead of whole path and extension?

Comment: `I have searched all over the internet`  seems unlikely.  Feeding your title + `c#` to Google returns 2.9 million hits

Answer (score 5):

The `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method will do this for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

Pass the results of GetFiles into the method and it should return what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which will just extract the file name only from the path back, so what you can do is project the `txtfiles` to get the collection of just filename like:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(txtfiles.Select(file=>Path.GetFileName(file));
```

and if you only need path, not actually reading them, you can use [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) method which would be better in memory performance which would be :

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(txtDirectory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.txt")
                                .Select(file=>Path.GetFileName(file))
                        );
```

Also if you only need name of file without extension then you can do as [Valuator answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715991/1875256) suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`

You could do something like

```
txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
var fileNames = txtfiles.Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```